# Try exception TypeError not loading properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, typeerror

I'm making an easy example of program that raises a TypeError exception. When it executes the operation in the `try` block, I expected it to jump directly to the exception block. But it only shows the TypeError, without making the exception.

Why doesn't it show the printed output that explains the error in the exception?

Here is my code:

```
entrada=input("escribe un valor para calcular su raiz: ")
raiz_cuadrada=entrada ** 0.5
try:
    if entrada>=0:
        print(raiz_cuadrada)
    else:
        print("no se puede calcular la raiz cuadrada de un numero negativo")
        raise ValueError
except TypeError:
    #This print below should be showed always as the input is a string always I think
    print("el valor proporcionado no es un número")
    raise TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

You had typo in entrada variable, it's string not int

Added input() in int()

The TypeError occured because it happened outside of try block exactly in raiz_cuadrda variable because you can't make exponentiation of string

Here's completed code

```
entrada=int(input("escribe un valor para calcular su raiz: "))
raiz_cuadrada=entrada ** 0.5
try:
    if entrada>=0:
        print(raiz_cuadrada)
    else:
        print("no se puede calcular la raiz cuadrada de un numero negativo")
        raise TypeError
except TypeError:
    #This print below should be showed always as the input is a string always I think
    print("el valor proporcionado no es un número")
    raise TypeError
```

Comment: Not the answer i'm searching. I want to force the typeError, but I dont understand why my exception is not working. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Well, you want to force TypeError with `raise` correct? Then  as in your question in try block you raised Value error and except only catches TypeError not ValueError. So you need to change `raise ValueError` to `raise TypeError` or `except TypeError` to `except ValueError` or if you want to catch all errors then `except Exception`.